# How does component rendering flows work in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I'm new to blazor (dotnet 8) and confused by how the component rendering flows work.

DataLayout:

```
       @if (currentSeason!=null && currentSeason.ActiveCategory.IsActive)
        {
            <CascadingValue Value="@currentSeason">
                <TTSWeb.Blazor.Components.Pages.Data.TeamsOnTop @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
                @Body
            </CascadingValue>
        }
        @code {
            
            [CascadingParameter]
            RouteData RouteData { get; set; }
            public string? Slug { get; set; }
            public CurrentSeasonModel currentSeason { get; set; } = new();
        
            protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
            {
                if (RouteData.RouteValues.TryGetValue("Slug", out var slug) == true)
                {
        
                     
                   var results = await ttsClient.LatestSeasonsByCategory.ExecuteAsync(slug!.ToString());
                   if (results.IsSuccessResult())
                   {
                      // load data to currentSeason  
                    }        
                }
              
            }
    }
```

On TeamsOnTop component:

```
@if (currentSeason != null && currentSeason.ActiveCategory.IsActive)
{ 
    <p>load teams</p>
}
else
{
   <p>no data</p>
}
    @code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public CurrentSeasonModel currentSeason { get; set; } = default!;
   }
```

the app hit **load teams** first, and then **no data**. So I wonder how it could possibly render the TeamsOnTop with a null currentSeason?

Answer (score 1):

When the component is created you set `currentSession`:

```cs
public CurrentSeasonModel currentSeason { get; set; } = new();
```

I'm betting that:

```cs
         // load data to currentSeason
```

does an async load of `currentSeason` that results in it either being `null` or `currentSeason.ActiveCategory.IsActive` is `false`.

As the operation is async and yields, the component renders and initializes (and potentially renders) any sub-components before it the bool test becomes false.  The component then renders a second time, the condition is false and nothing sets rendered.

I'm not sure why you are conditionally rendering `@body`, but you probably have your reasons.

*Suggestions*:

You are checking for null so use `nullables` and don't check in the layout.

```cs
  <CascadingValue Value="@currentSeason">
     <TTSWeb.Blazor.Components.Pages.Data.TeamsOnTop @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
                @Body
  </CascadingValue>
@code {
            public CurrentSeasonModel? currentSeason { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```cs
@if (currentSeason != null && currentSeason.ActiveCategory.IsActive)
{ 
    <p>load teams</p>
}
else
{
   <p>no data</p>
}
    @code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public CurrentSeasonModel? currentSeason { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: thanks, yes currentSeason get async load, in this case, any suggestions what I can do to make sure the sub-components gets the non null currentSeason ?

Comment: See my updated answer based on the code you've provided.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's still the same. I'll try to get rid off CascadingParam and use injected Service/Parameter instead.